# How can i change ::selection in mui createTheme

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to change ::selection ( color and bg color ) globally in my app, I wanted to know how can I do it using createTheme()

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution!

```
...

MuiCssBaseline: {
  styleOverrides: {
    body: {
      '& ::selection': {
        color: 'red',
        background: 'yellow',
      },
    },
  },
},

...
```